# Sqlite doesn't work on actual device (on my iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I've written a simple app that uses Sqlite database. It works great on iPhone simulator but doesn't work on my iPhone.

```
-(NSString *) getFilePath
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sql"];
}

-(void)openDatabase
{
    //Open

    if (sqlite3_open([[self getFilePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK ) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open.");
    }
}
```

Output on Xcode after launching app:

```
2013-03-07 02:12:16.525 SqliteWorkApp[464:907] *** Assertion failure in -[SqliteWorkAppViewController insertRecord], /Users/cmltkt/Objective-C Apps/SqliteWorkApp/SqliteWorkApp/SqliteWorkAppViewController.m:77
2013-03-07 02:12:16.529 SqliteWorkApp[464:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error updating table.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3398e2a3 0x3b82797f 0x3398e15d 0x34263ab7 0x19b3b 0x195bd 0x357b5595 0x357f5d79 0x357f1aed 0x358331e9 0x357f683f 0x357ee84b 0x35796c39 0x357966cd 0x3579611b 0x374885a3 0x374881d3 0x33963173 0x33963117 0x33961f99 0x338d4ebd 0x338d4d49 0x357ed485 0x357ea301 0x19147 0x3bc5eb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

insertRecord function:

```
-(void)insertRecord
{
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 'countries' ('name', 'flag') " "VALUES ('Sample Data','Sample Data')"];

    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err)
        != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Error updating table.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is in your `insertRecord` method. Show the code for that method.

Comment: Also, does the actual file exist in the Documents directory on your device? As written, your app simply opens an empty (non-existent) database. You either need to copy a pre-made database file with all the empty tables or you need to execute the SQL to create the tables.

Comment: @rmaddy makes a good point; unless you include a preconfigured database in the bundle the first thing you need to do is create the database and its schema.

Comment: I added my insertRecord function to my question and yes database.sql is located in documents directory?

Comment: @CemilTokatlı The database file will not exist the first time the app is run. Your app needs to initialize the database file. Your insert will fail because the table doesn't exist. Do you have code that creates the tables in the database file in the Documents directory?

Comment: ohh, I just realized, It didn't create a table on device and trying to insert record to the table but it doesnt exists. I fixed code and works great. Thank you for your interest in my problem @maddy ;)

Comment: the sqlite database extension is ".sqlite" not ".sql"

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem,

I used SQLite Db portable file in app and It was working on simulator very well but not on real device.

So after digging a lot, I found, when I dragged sqlite db file into my project, Xcode did not add it to bundle resources.

*Please! go this way*

1. select your project go to "Build Phases"
2. add your **database.sqlite** (it should be. sqlite as i know) file to Bundle resources.

[image]

and For handling all SQLite stuff, my database helper class code is

```
#import "ASCODBHelper.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@implementation ASCODBHelper

static ASCODBHelper *db;


+(ASCODBHelper *)database{

    if (db == nil) {

        db = [[ASCODBHelper alloc] init];
    }

    return db;
}

- (id)init{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IOSMeeting" ofType:@"sqlite"];

        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {

            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");       
        }

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)getPresentationDeatilById:(NSString *)presentationid andSessionId:(NSString *)sessionid{

    NSInteger pId = [presentationid integerValue];
    NSInteger sId = [sessionid integerValue];

    NSString *queryString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT distinct mediaID,mediaURL,meetingName,trackName FROM Media WHERE presentationID='%d' and sessionID ='%d'",pId,sId];

    NSLog(@"query is  : %@",queryString);

    sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [queryString UTF8String], -1, &selectStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            char *mediaid = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 0);
            char *mediaurl = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1);
            char *meetingname = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2);
            char *topicname = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 3);

            NSString *mediaID = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:mediaid];
            NSString *mediaURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:mediaurl];
            NSString *topicName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:topicname];
            NSString *meetingName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:meetingname];

            //you can log here results            

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement);
    }  
}        

@end
```

and Here is the code how I am using this.

Just import

```
#import "ASCODBHelper.h"
```

and call our db helper method this way

```
[[ASCODBHelper database] getPresentationDeatilById:presentationId andSessionId:sessionId];
```

Let me know if need help in this.